# Random sampling the data again to keep equal size across groups

Tags: sample-size, small-sample

I have an experiment with a between-group variable. It has 3 groups in total. When conducting the experiment, although we did random assignment for participants, the size of the 3 groups end up differently: 15, 21 and 27, respectively.

With the data I want to conduct one-way ANOVA. I also have a repeated-measure variable, with which I also want to conduct mixed ANOVA. Currently my data violates the homogeneity of variance assumption.

It seems with balanced group size ANOVA is pretty robust against the violation but not if sizes are unbalanced ([reference](http://www.basic.northwestern.edu/statguidefiles/oneway_anova_ass_viol.html#Special%20problems%20with%20imbalanced%20sample%20sizes)).

My questions is, could I randomly sample the 2 bigger groups again (without replacement) into size of 15, so that to keep the size equal across groups? If so, is there any theoretical support for that?

Or I should just use robust non-parametric methods instead?

Comment: If possible you want to avoid throwing out the extra $(21-15)+(27-15)=18$ subjects ($29\%$ of the total) because that substantially reduces the power of the data.  What statistical procedures, exactly, do you wish to perform that cannot be accomplished with unequal group sizes?

Comment: yes I understand the loss of power. I want to do ANOVA. I actually have another repeated-measure variable, therefore it is mixed ANOVA. when group size is unequal it violates assumptions of ANOVA.

Comment: It is not obvious which assumptions would be violated. Your question suggests you might be equating "different group sizes" with "different variances," but those two things are completely unrelated. Instead of asking about the validity of subsampling, your question might produce answers of more use to you if you were to edit it to explain what assumptions you think have been violated (and why) and then ask for suggestions about what to do.

Comment: you are right. I edited to add explanation. Please see if it makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense. But I still wonder about the *evidence* you have that your groups might have unequal variances.  What diagnostic tests have you performed in order to check this assumption and what were their results?

Comment: I used Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance. The result on my data is significant, which means the variances are significantly different.

Comment: IMO, with the current sample size, while I reserve the power, if I cannot use the normal ANOVA, since the robust methods are usually more conservative, the result would still lose power eventually.

Comment: It would be better to analyze the data without assuming equal variances in the groups!  Not particularly difficult to do that nowadays.  Or, maybe, some transformation of the data can homogenize the variances?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen do you mean robust methods? they still lose power. I have still been thinking about transformation, as my data has their own equations and meaning, transformed data would represent a different meaning.

Comment: To get some better opinions, you should say more about your data and your goals with the analysis!